# DesignSurface: Can't delete controls

Tags: c#, winforms, invalidoperationexception

I'm currently working on a project involving DesignSurfaces.

In the Form_load event, I load a form with 3 textboxes, 3 labels and a button.
To manage these controls, I have a ContextMenuStrip with MenuItems containing the `StandardCommands` Cut, Copy, Paste and Delete.
However, when I try any of these actions, It'll throw an `InvalidOperationException` which says something like "The inherited component 'textBox1' cannot be deleted" (Unfortunately, I don't have the exception message in english, but through googling I found that it might be this one: "Cannot remove or destroy inherited component")
If I add a control runtime and try to delete it, everything works fine (Cut, Copy, Paste too).

Here's the code for the ContextMenuStrip:

```
public void ShowContextMenu( CommandID menuID, int x, int y ) {
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            MenuCommand command = FindCommand( StandardCommands.Cut );
            if( command != null ) {
                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem( "Cut", new EventHandler( OnMenuClicked ) );
                menuItem.Tag = command;
                contextMenu.MenuItems.Add( menuItem );
            }
            command = FindCommand( StandardCommands.Copy );
            if( command != null ) {
                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem( "Copy", new EventHandler( OnMenuClicked ) );
                menuItem.Tag = command;
                contextMenu.MenuItems.Add( menuItem );
            }
            command = FindCommand( StandardCommands.Paste );
            if( command != null ) {
                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem( "Paste", new EventHandler( OnMenuClicked ) );
                menuItem.Tag = command;
                contextMenu.MenuItems.Add( menuItem );
            }
            command = FindCommand( StandardCommands.Delete );
            if( command != null ) {
                MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem( "Delete", new EventHandler( OnMenuClicked ) );
                menuItem.Tag = command;
                contextMenu.MenuItems.Add( menuItem );
            }

            DesignSurface surface = (DesignSurface) _serviceProvider;
            Control viewService = (Control) surface.View;

            if( viewService != null ) {
                contextMenu.Show( viewService, viewService.PointToClient( new Point( x, y ) ) );
            }
        }


private void OnMenuClicked( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
            if( menuItem != null && menuItem.Tag is MenuCommand ) {
                MenuCommand command = menuItem.Tag as MenuCommand;
                command.Invoke();
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out what the problem is here.

Did someone here experience a similiar issue? Or any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I meant "Form Load" event and not "Program Load" event. I'll fix this.

Comment: Are you hosting the designer?

Comment: How do you mean "hosting"?

Comment: Meaning providing design time functionality outside of Visual Studio. You are using the design surface here but not checking if the system is in design-time, so I'm confused how you get the design surface from the service provider.

Comment: Everything I talk about is in runtime. To create the designSurface, I am using an extended class from CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24385/Have-a-Great-DesignTime-Experience-with-a-Powerful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an empty form instead and manually adding the required components.